# Cross-sectional area of a parallel beam of light is invariant under Lorentz transformations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I was trying to solve padmanabhan's problem "Show that the cross-sectional area of a parallel beam of light is invariant under Lorentz transformations." [Hint. Argue as follows: if $k^i$ is the null four-vector along which the light beam is traveling, the cross-sectional area is defined by two other purely spacelike vectors $a^i$ and $b^i$ such that $k^ib_i = k^ia_i = 0$. Take the area to be a small square so that $a^ib_i = 0$. A different observer will have the corresponding vectors $a'^i$ and $b'^i$. Argue that one must have $a'^i = a^i + \alpha k^i$ and $b'^i = b^i + \beta k^i$. Determine $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by the condition that the primed vectors must be orthogonal to $u^i$ which is the four-velocity of the observer. Compute the area determined by $a'^i$, $b'^i$, and show that it is the same as the one determined by $a^i$, $b^i$.]$$$$ 
In the given hint he asked to argue that one must have $a'^i = a^i + \alpha k^i$ and $b'^i = b^i + \beta k^i$. Can anyone explain, why it is true?